# Scroll Callback or Listener for Chrome Custom Tab Android

Tags: android, android-intent, chrome-custom-tabs

I am looking for following 2 solutions related to **Chrome Custom Tab** in Android:

1. Listener or Callback if the page url was completely loaded (i.e. 100%)
2. Listener or Callback for  page scroll or if the page scrolled to the end/bottom.

Both are possible by implementing ***WebView*** but I don't know how to do same with **Chrome Custom Tab**. I searched everywhere for best possible solutions but didn't found a way.

So can anyone please guide me is it possible with **Chrome Custom Tab** or not?

If yes how I implement it in Android?

**UPDATE:**

I found something that may be related to 1st point [CustomTabsCallback##NAVIGATION_FINISHED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/customtabs/CustomTabsCallback#NAVIGATION_FINISHED) but didn't found a example that works.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, following is the callback method we should implement.

```
void onNavigationEvent(int navigationEvent, Bundle extras)
```

where `navigationEvent` is as follows

```
/**
 * Sent when the tab has started loading a page.
 */
public static final int NAVIGATION_STARTED = 1;

/**
 * Sent when the tab has finished loading a page.
 */
public static final int NAVIGATION_FINISHED = 2;

/**
 * Sent when the tab couldn't finish loading due to a failure.
 */
public static final int NAVIGATION_FAILED = 3;

/**
 * Sent when loading was aborted by a user action before it finishes like 
   clicking on a link
 * or refreshing the page.
 */
public static final int NAVIGATION_ABORTED = 4;

/**
 * Sent when the tab becomes visible.
 */
public static final int TAB_SHOWN = 5;

/**
 * Sent when the tab becomes hidden.
 */
public static final int TAB_HIDDEN = 6;
```

You can find using onNavigationEvent implementation in https://github.com/GoogleChrome/custom-tabs-client/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/org/chromium/customtabsclient/MainActivity.java#L111. Here is full sample demo project https://github.com/GoogleChrome/custom-tabs-client from Google itself.

Reference: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/custom-tabs-client/blob/master/Using.md#navigation

For question 2, I am not sure whether there is currently a way to do this but I am not 100% sure.